# Please do not "axe" me a question?

Tags: pronunciation

Although I hesitate to ask this question, I see it as necessary to promote common proper word usage. I certainly never want to appear arrogant or offend anyone, but I have noticed that there is one word that is commonly misused, primarily in metropolitan areas. Why must people “*axe*” for or about something?
When I first arrived in the city, a new acquaintance, who is my now dearest friend, said that she had to “*axe* me a question.” Fortunately, before I panicked she quickly continued to “*axe*” me what I planned to have for dinner that night. For several years I have heard “*axe*” incorrectly repeated in this context, and I sincerely wish to simply correct those who are using it improperly. However, I have heard and seen angry confrontations when someone insists that when one is ‘*axing* a question”, they might try instead to “ask a question.”  Even the mildest of attempts to persuade them of their improper use of the verb "axe” in the present tense is typically ignored if not met with outright contempt. Every time I now hear the word misused, it becomes more wrenching. 
I work as an editor, so every day I refine the words of people who are renowned in their areas of expertise but who cannot properly enter words into a document. Together we work as a team to submit properly worded bids on multi-million-dollar contracts. Does anyone have a gentle, but effective way to correct this error that I seem to hear so frequently?

Comment: This is an interpersonal question, and [best suited there](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/). How to correct someone's speech tactfully and respectfully is never easy, and possibly none of your business in the first place.

Comment: The word is not being "misused" at all. The speaker is simply using a dialect pronunciation which doesn't correspond to your over-prescriptive definition of "English." In some parts of the UK, "aks" is the *standard* pronunciation (in the sense that everybody who was raised in that region would use it), not "ask".  (And I suggest you don't ever go to South Yorkshire, where words like "coal" and "hole" are pronounced "coil" and "oil"...)